# SQL Server query. Where user exists in another table but not the user

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL server query which I am trying to achieve but am struggling to find the right words to describe it to look on MSDN. What I have is a table of data and a table of users. I want to create a loop that for each user in dbo.Users to count the records in dbo.Data where the user is the NOT current user in loop, but is a user listed in dbo.Users.

ie.

```
SELECT COUNT(Records) 
FROM dbo.Data 
WHERE User <> 'ajones' AND (User = 'jbloggs' OR User ='jdoe')
```

(Where ajones is the current user and jbloggs and jdoe are users listed in dbo.Users).

So the "OR" expression will have every single user other than the user it is searching for, that exists in dbo.Users

I can't do WHERE <> 'ajones' (the current user) because there are many users in the dbo.Data table, but only some those users appear in dbo.Users.

Does this make sense? Some pseudo code:

```
FOR EACH User in dbo.Users
    SELECT COUNT(Records) 
    FROM dbo.Data 
    WHERE User <> CurrentUser AND User IN dbo.Users
Loop
```

What would be the best way to achieve this kind of query?

Comment: do you have user id's in both tables or just usernames? and do you have some sample data and desired output to illustrate what you're after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(Records) 
FROM dbo.Data 
WHERE User <> 'ajones' AND User in (select distinct user from dbo.Users)
```

Comment: Your answer is probably right. But it is better in StackOverflow to add comments about pieces of code, to explain why that answer the question.

Comment: I don't think a developer requires to be that much descriptive...everything is very much explained by by the sql code

Comment: One sentence of explaining can help a beginner developer who has the same problem as the original poster. I agree that it may not be always needed. I added a comment to your answer because that answer was in the list of low quality posts, in the review queue for reviewers.

Comment: The other answer also doesn't have any comments. Was that also low quality post? May I know a little more about "low quality"?

Comment: I do not know. At the page http://stackoverflow.com/review all memebrs of SO with more then 2000 reputation can review the queue of "low quality posts". I do not know what are the criteria to be in that queue, and not all reviewers see all the post of the queue.

Comment: I understood it...anybody having 15+ reputation can flag a post as low quality..Simple things usually look low quality to people having less reputation

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(Records) 
FROM dbo.Data D
INNER JOIN dbo.Users U
ON U.User = D.User
WHERE D.User <> 'ajones'
```